# How to render list inside list in flutter?

Tags: list, dart, flutter, widget

I'm creating an flutter app which should show list of teams, and each team is an object with items like

`name`: string

`players`: array of

`name`: string

so it looks like this

```
List teams = [
      {
        'name': 'Team one',
        'players': [
          {
            'name': 'Team one player one',
          },
          {
            'name': 'Team one player two',
          },
          {
            'name': 'Team one player three',
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        'name': 'Team two',
        'players': [
          {
            'name': 'Team two player one',
          },
          {
            'name': 'Team two player one',
          },
          {
            'name': 'Team two player three',
          },
        ]
      },
    ];
```

Further, in my code, I'm iterating through all `teams` with `ListView`, like this

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: renderTeams(teams),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and `renderTeams()` looks like this:

```
  Widget renderTeams(List teams) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: teams.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(teams[index]['name']),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: PlayerCard(
                      player: teams[index]['players'][0],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: PlayerCard(
                      player: teams[index]['players'][1],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: PlayerCard(
                      player: teams[index]['players'][2],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This works well, everything gets rendered accordingly.

However, I'd like to, instead adding each player separately, iterate through each's team players, so my `renderTeams()` would look like this:

```
  Widget renderTeams(List teams) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: teams.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Text(teams[index]['name']),
              renderPlayers(teams[index]['players'])
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

and `renderPlayers()` looks like this:

```
  renderPlayers(players) {
    return Row(children: players.map((player) => {
        Flexible(
          child: PlayerCard(
            player: player,
          ),
      )
    }).toList());
  }
```

This is where my troubles begin, as I'm getting errors like

`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'`

And I've googled around, but other responses, tried to fix types, but that leads me into infinite loop of trying to fix errors i do not understand.

Anyone got any hint? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `{` `}`

```
renderPlayers(players) {
  return Row(children: players.map((player) => 
      Flexible(
        child: PlayerCard(
          player: player,
      ),
    )
  ).toList());
}
```

**Explanation**

`=>` means `return`. `=> { ... }` means returning a function (dynamic). That's why it was detected as `List<dynamic>`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but this is not working. I'm getting same error as above.

Comment: Although, on the second try, your answer opened another set of possibilities for me, and by using your code and just adding List before parameter `players`, it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432234/how-to-set-the-list-of-json-data-inside-list-in-the-listview-builder-in-flutter

Answer (score -1):

**Use Spread Operator [...]**

The best solution for this type of problem is the *Spreed Operator [...]*. The spread operator combines two or more list instances. It also extends a collection's elements of a such as a list.
You can use it with Columns, Rows or Listview.
Like this:

```
// List
final variableValuesList = [
VariablesWithValues(
 title: 'a',
 value: 1,
),
VariablesWithValues(
 title: 'b',
 value: 1,
),
];

  /// using inside column
  Column(
   children: [
     ///getting values from the list through spread operator
    ...variableValuesList.map((item) => Text(${item.title} = ${item.value})
      ).toList(),
```